# How do we compare elements in two lists in a Where Clause (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq

```
class objA
{
    public Rectangle area;    
}

class objB
{
    public Point somepoint;
}


List<objA> listA;
List<objB> listB;
```

Now, I want to get the elements in listA and listB wherever `objA.area.contains(objB.point)`

Comment: What have you tried? What is expected result if rectangle **A** contains points **X** and **Y**, and rectangle **C** contains point **X**?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
result = listA.Select(a=>
new{ 
    Rectangle = a, 
    Points =listB.Where(b=>a.Contains(b))
});
```

Comment: +1 Looks like what OP wants. Consider name properties `Rectanle` and `Points`

Answer (score 0):

You might consider doing a `from from where` style query, which is also called a non-equi join:

```
from rect in listA
from point in listB
where rect.Area.Contains(point.SomePoint)
select new { rect, point }
```